# Iterate through DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which looks like this:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
--------+---------+--------
10      | 10      |
20      | 20      |
30      | 30      |
```

I'd like to iterate through this DataGridView and calculate A+B. The result should be in column C.

What i tried so far is:

```
foreach (Datagridview rw in datagridview1.Rows)
{
    int result = rw.Cells["ColumnA"].Value.ToString() + 
                 rw.Cells["ColumnB"].Value.ToString();
    rw.Cells["ColumnB"] = result.ToString();
}
```

But this is not going to work. I get the first column filled but the other columns are emtpy.

Can anyone show me how I can iterate through a DataGridView and take each value of the row to calculate and then move to the next row.

Comment: You are adding strings. You actually should add integers. Maybe something like `(int)rw.Cells["ColumnA"].Value + (int)rw.Cells["ColumnB"].Value` would work better?

Comment: Can you show how you populate datagridview with the data? DataGridView is just a control to display data, data can and should be totally different object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @uwe-keim comments, you are adding strings, you need to paste the cells value to integer fist.

This should work for you:

```
foreach (Datagridview rw in datagridview1.Rows)
{
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(rw.Cells["ColumnA"].Value) + 
                 Convert.ToInt32(rw.Cells["ColumnB"].Value);
    rw.Cells["ColumnB"] = result.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to be able to manage also float, `Convert.ToSingle()` comes to your aid. Replace it instead of `Convert.ToInt32()` and all the valid strings will be converted to float. (Same with `Convert.ToDouble()`).

If you want to verify the presence of strings instead you can use the `TryParse()` function that will return you true or false depending on whether the string can be converted into a number or not.

```
decimal result = 0;
Console.WriteLine(decimal.TryParse("hello", out result));
```

Comment: ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD
    --------+---------+--------+--------+--------
    10      | 10      | Hello      |
    20      | 20,50      | World     |
    30      | 30      | Hello1      |

Can you also show me how i solve the problem when i also have float numbers.

And another thing is that i want to take the string in column C as an output. 

It Should like this.
   ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | Name
    --------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------
    10      | 10      | Hello      | 20      | Hello
    for all rows

Comment: @emciv I have updated the answer, let me know if the information added is what you need, in that case, if you could mark the answer as solved would be great, otherwise let me know and I will try to help you more

Answer (score 1):

Don't work directly with `DataGridView`. Use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) instead.

For example, you can use the good old `DataTable` for storing and processing data.
Give it a telling name that lets you know exactly what is stored in it, instead of `some`.

```
// form field
DataTable someDataTable;
```

Create it. Perhaps you should have some other type than `int`. For example, `float` or `double`.

```
someDataTable = new DataTable();
someDataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnA", typeof(int));
someDataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnB", typeof(int));
someDataTable.Columns.Add("ColumnC", typeof(int), "ColumnA + ColumnB");
```

Note that we specified an expression for the `ColumnC` column. Now the value in this column will be calculated automatically.

Bind DataTable to DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = someDataTable;
```

Fill some data:

```
someDataTable.Rows.Add(10, 10);
someDataTable.Rows.Add(20, 20);
someDataTable.Rows.Add(30, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView is just a view control which responsibility is to display data.
Instead of manipulating DataGridView cells, use "right tool for the job" - an object.

Create a class to represent one row

```
public class Row
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total => Price * Quantity; // Here we calculate third column
}
```

Create a collection of records to display in DataGridView

```
// In Form_Load for example

var firstRow = new Row { Price = 199, Quantity = 2 };
var secondRow = new Row { Price = 49, Quantity = 100 };

var allRows = new BindingList<Row>();
allRows.Add(firstRow);
allRows.Add(secondRow);

// Set DataGridView.DataSource to created list
datagridview1.DataSource = allRows;
```